# Add Quillbot API to Google Sheets

Tags: api, google-sheets

I have just discovered GPT-3 and found Quillbot website. I got suscribed, but I want to add their paraphrase function into Google Sheets.

I found that Google Sheets has a section where you can add functions via API. In order to apply this actions in bulk.

When you have a Quillbot premium account, you get an Api.

I have been searching if there is already something done. But I have not found it. Just this: https://rapidapi.com/quillbotapi-quillbotapi-default/api/quillbot-paraphraser

Can someone please help me to do this function in Google Sheets?

Thank you very much.